# Get the count by type in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble getting the count by its type.

[image: Object]

[image]

How do I get the count of Home (PartnerIntegrationbTesting.Context.Home)? There are 4 items in the List (quoteList.Products)

Comment: There's two puzzle pieces here. First is to determine if an object is of a particular type. Second is to filter and count a list. Which are you having problems with?

Comment: Also, why are you using `dynamic`, and why are you allowing your list to contain multiple different data types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.Count()` with a filtering function. `is` will test if the left-hand object is the type specified on the right.

```
var countOfHomeProducts = quoteList.Products
   .Count(p => p is PartnerIntegrationbTesting.Context.Home);
```

Comment: And I have to stress. Don't use `dynamic` unless you have a **VERY GOOD REASON**. If you're not 100% sure, and know exactly the ins and outs of dynamic, **DON'T USE IT**.

Comment: Oh, man, you just gotta love all the random runtime errors when using dynamics. Don't miss the thrill!

Comment: Na man, I don't miss that hell. Powershell's got it even worse, and JavaScript's basically _built_ on the idea of dynamic.

Comment: Great thanks man, Yea i am not happy with the way i use dynamic but could not thin of a other way of simplifying it.  I started of with adding separate list times for each type like
 public class Quote
    {
        public List<Home> Homes { get; set; } = new List<Home>();
        public List<Motor> Motors { get; set; } = new List<Motor>();
}
It is not easy to use separate List<obj>and convert them to a paylod. Having dynamic is the simplest way that I could have multiple different types in one object

Comment: Look into making an interface or base class rather than dynamic.

Comment: @Budd, like gunr said, can't they inherit from a common base class for instance? What do they have in common to be in a list?

Comment: Yea, I am 100% with you guys. I will look into making it an interface :) Thanks guys